# I can't use rviz in host PC

Tags: ros, rviz, remote-launch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My purpose is  executing navigation to my handmade robot. I have 2 PCs.
I'd like to see the rviz and set the goal position from host PC remotely.
And I 'd like to control remote PC on the robot to execute amcl.launch.

I have already executed amcl.launch remotely on the remote PC,
but I couldn't see the map of rviz from host PC.
I thought that it looks like rviz didn't get the information of remote PC.
Therefore,I executed "rqt_graph"on my host PC, then I could see some nodes.
From this result , I found that my host PC and remote PC are capable of communicating each other.

Please let me know how to see the rviz from my host PC?

---

Edit: I configured commands as the following procedure.

> [1] setting of IP Address and name

```
on Host(NotePC)
I executed "sudo gedit /etc/hosts" and save the following parameter
    192.168.122.22 NotePC
    192.168.122.33 mori

on remote PC(mori)
I executed same command.
    192.168.122.22 NotePC
    192.168.122.33 mori
```

> [2] start roscore I executed the following command to start roscore in host(NotePC)

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=Notepc 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.122.22:11311 
export ROS_IP=192.168.122.22 
roscore
```

> [3] connect to remotePC

```
ssh mori@mori -p 22
export ROS_HOSTNAME=mori
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.122.22:11311 
export ROS_IP=192.168.122.33 
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
roslaunch  myrobo_navigation amcl.launch
```

> [4] rqt_graph

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=Notepc 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.122.22:11311 
export ROS_IP=192.168.122.22 
rqt_graph
```

Then, The diagram is appeared the following.
And I can't see the tf(I also checked it by executing "rosrun tf view_frames").

[image: image description]

If I execute roscore and the step [3] only on the remote PC .
I can get the following diagram. And I can see tf tree and rviz.

[image: image description]

My launch file "amcl.launch" is the following:

```
<launch>
  <machine name="mori" address="mori" env-loader="/home/mori/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh" user="mori" password="ubuntu"/>
  <arg name="launch_rviz" default="true"/>
  <arg name="with_camera" default="true"/>

  <!-- RPLider.launch -->
  <node machine="mori" name="rplidarNode" pkg="rplidar_ros"  type="rplidarNode" output="screen">
      <param name="serial_port"         type="string" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>  
      <param name="serial_baudrate"     type="int"    value="115200"/>
      <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="laser"/>
      <param name="inverted"            type="bool"   value="false"/>
      <param name="angle_compensate"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
  </node>

  <!-- odometry_tf -->
  <node machine="mori" pkg="odometry_tf" type="odometry_tf_node" name="odometry_tf_node"/>

  <!-- Map server -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find myrobo_navigation)/map/map.yaml"/>
  <node machine="mori" name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find myrobo_navigation)/launch/include/laser_amcl.launch.xml"/>

  <!-- Move base -->
  <include file="$(find myrobo_navigation)/launch/include/move_base.launch.xml"/>

  <node machine="mori" if="$(arg with_camera)" name="image_transport" pkg="image_transport" type="republish" args="compressed in:=/raspicam_node/image raw out:=/camera/image_raw"/>

   <!-- usb_cam -->
  <node machine="mori" name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
  </node>

  <!-- image_view -->
  <node machine="mori" name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false">
    <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>

 <!-- Rviz -->
  <node machine="mori" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find myrobo_navigation)/launch/include/amcl.rviz"/>

</launch>
```

Please let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281231/i-can%27t-use-rviz-in-host-pc/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rdelgadov](https://answers.ros.org/users/33433/rdelgadov/) on 2018-01-30**:
Do you set 'ROS_IP' in both computers?

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2018-01-31**:
Yes,I have already set "ROS_IP" on each PC.

**Comment by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on 2018-02-10**:
Do you solve your problem?
I'm facing similar problem with hector slam, between a RasPi an a laptop.
But, in my case, changing the network, sometimes, it works. ie using an external router as AP, instead of using PI as AP and laptop connected to PI...

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2018-02-16**:
I have not resolved it yet. Thank you for your advice, I will try it.

**Comment by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on 2018-02-16**:
I found my problem!!!
It was time issue.
When I test with my home router, both PC and PI connect to it and get their clock sinchroniced from internet.
But, when I goes to the river, where the router don't has internet connection, then PI has different time than PC and don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the Network debugging guide: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

For basic instrucitons see http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2018-01-31**:
Thank you for your reply. But I think that it is not problem of the network.
when I executed amcl.launch on remote PC, The published topics are less than when executing it only on remote PC. So, does it have problems on my launch file ?